# How to get sound pressure level (dB) of audio in Python?

Tags: python, pyaudio

I wonder that how to get sound pressure level in dB in Python? The input should be the signal from the microphone of PC (real-time audio signal). The output is the real-time sound pressure level of input signal. I have written a simple code which needs to be developed. Thanks very much.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Apr 21 17:22:10 2017

@author: YuanGao
"""

import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import wave

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100

pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = pa.open(format=FORMAT,
                         channels=CHANNELS,
                         rate=RATE,
                         input=True,
                         frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

buffer = []
while True:
    string_audio_data = stream.read(CHUNK) 
    audio_data = np.fromstring(string_audio_data, dtype=np.short)

    print(audio_data)
```

Comment: Is this not part of the documentation for the input signal?  What do you see for input, and what help do you need in the conversion?  The audio feeds I've seen are simple enough: add up the intensities across all frequencies and take the log (i.e. definition of dB).